# 3 Column Lists Using HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

actually i have this code in my html:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
<ul>
<li>Left Item 1</li>
<li>Left Item 2</li>
<li>Left Item 3</li>
<li>Left Item 4</li>
<li>Left Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
<ul>
<li>Middle Item 1</li>
<li>Middle Item 2</li>
<li>Middle Item 3</li>
<li>Middle Item 4</li>
<li>Middle Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 33%;">
<ul>
<li>Right Item 1</li>
<li>Right Item 2</li>
<li>Right Item 3</li>
<li>Right Item 4</li>
<li>Right Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

now i want to do the same think so i use a variable present in my `$scope`, it looks like:

```
var descritpion='Peinture métal|Toit ouvrant électrique|ABS|Airbag genoux|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux AV et AR|Antipatinage|Clim automatique bi-zones|Détecteur de sous-gonflage|Direction assistée|ESP|Filtre à particules|Jantes Alu|Ordinateur de bord|Pack automatique|Pack automatique II|Phares antibrouillard|Phares xénon directionnels|Radar de recul|Radio CD MP3|Régulateur-Limiteur de vitesse|Rétroviseurs électriques dégivrants|Rétroviseurs rabattables électriquement|Sellerie cuir & tissu|Sièges avant électriques|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres arrière électriques|Vitres electriques avant'
$scope.description=description;
```

how can i do to do a three colum list from `$scope.description`..?

(i want to take element three at a time and put them in left middle and right)

***update:***

my html:

```
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="EquipementsSerieEtOption in car.EquipementsSerieEtOption">
                {{EquipementsSerieEtOption}}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

my js:

...

```
data.data.EquipementsSerieEtOption = data.data.EquipementsSerieEtOption.split('|');
        $scope.car = data.data;
```

...

Comment: `split()` into array and use `ng-repeat`

Comment: It's unclear how you want the description string to be displayed.  Did you want it to take elements three at a time and put them in left, middle, and right?

Comment: @ryanyuyu yes i want to take element three at a time and put them in left middle and right

Comment: And is a requirement to use `<ul>` or will an HTML `<table>` also work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

    var description = 'Peinture métal|Toit ouvrant électrique|ABS|Airbag genoux|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux AV et AR|Antipatinage|Clim automatique bi-zones|Détecteur de sous-gonflage|Direction assistée|ESP|Filtre à particules|Jantes Alu|Ordinateur de bord|Pack automatique|Pack automatique II|Phares antibrouillard|Phares xénon directionnels|Radar de recul|Radio CD MP3|Régulateur-Limiteur de vitesse|Rétroviseurs électriques dégivrants|Rétroviseurs rabattables électriquement|Sellerie cuir & tissu|Sièges avant électriques|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres arrière électriques|Vitres electriques avant'

    $scope.descriptions = description.split('|');

  });
```

```css
.one.third {
  width: 33.333333%;
  float: left;
}
.box {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div class="one third box" ng-repeat="d in descriptions">
    <ul>
      <li>{{d}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use css columns, you can simply update one list and it will handle the layout:

```
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an HTML table, but you could adapt this code to use list elements.

In the javascript, I first split the string into an array of strings.  Then I loop through the string array (3 elements at a time) to create an object array.

```
$scope.description ='Peinture métal|Toit ouvrant électrique|ABS|Airbag genoux|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux AV et AR|Antipatinage|Clim automatique bi-zones|Détecteur de sous-gonflage|Direction assistée|ESP|Filtre à particules|Jantes Alu|Ordinateur de bord|Pack automatique|Pack automatique II|Phares antibrouillard|Phares xénon directionnels|Radar de recul|Radio CD MP3|Régulateur-Limiteur de vitesse|Rétroviseurs électriques dégivrants|Rétroviseurs rabattables électriquement|Sellerie cuir & tissu|Sièges avant électriques|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres arrière électriques|Vitres electriques avant';
var strArray = $scope.description.split("|");

//create the objectArray
$scope.objList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i+=3) {
    $scope.objList.push({
      left: strArray[i],
      middle: strArray[i+1],
      right: strArray[i+2]
    });
}
```

Then I used `ng-repeat` to draw the HTML.  I like repeating HTML table rows.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Left</td>
      <td>Middle</td>
      <td>Right</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat='element in objList'>
      <td>{{element.left}}</td>
      <td>{{element.middle}}</td>
      <td>{{element.right}}</td>
    </tr>          
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a2CwZeX6xSNbNf3acmSM)